# Is it possible to have a defined name that applies multiple cells via relative reference?

Tags: excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a cell with numerous relative references pointing back to it that span multiple sheets; is it possible to define a name for that original cell and have it apply to all of the other linked cells dynamically? The defined name will need to be changed often. I need to format all of the aforementioned cells dynamically so I was hoping I could use the name to refer to all of them in a formula. Using VBA isn't an option in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

A defined name can refer to, for example:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!C1,,-2)+OFFSET(Sheet2!C1,,-2)+OFFSET(Sheet3!C1,,-2)
```

Placed in C1 of Sheet4 it should sum whatever is in A1 across Sheets1 - 3 both inclusive and A2 across Sheets1 - 3 both inclusive if dragged down one cell, and so forth.